# `ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` when pipe character (|) in GET request query parameter in Wildfly 21

Tags: java, spring, rest, encoding, wildfly

We've recently migrated a Spring REST application from ***Wildfly 15.0.1.Final*** to ***Wildfly 21.0.0.Final*** which apparently introduced an issue with `GET` requests: whenever we have a `|` (pipe) character in the query parameter string of the `GET` request, the request returns no response and we get `ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.

I know that '|' (pipe) character is unsafe according to the RFC1738 specification of HTTP, while RFC3986 allows for the encoding of Unicode characters.

I would like this to keep working though, as we have external clients sending requests with `|` character in the query parameter, and currently if we would move to the current Wildfly 21 config, those requests would fail.

The same configuration was working fine on ***Wildfly 15.0.1.Final***.

I have these in `standalone.xml` with no avail:

```xml
 <system-properties>
      <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/>
      <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING" value="true"/>
 </system-properties>
```

```xml
<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" allow-unescaped-characters-in-url="true" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true" url-charset="UTF-8" />
<https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" max-post-size="1048576000" allow-unescaped-characters-in-url="true" ssl-context="LocalhostSslContext" enable-http2="true" url-charset="UTF-8" />
```

...and this in `standalone.conf.bat`:

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING=UTF-8"
```

The very same code on the very same VM, with (migrated) config works fine on ***Wildfly 15.0.1.Final*** but throws the `ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` in ***Wildfly 21.0.0.Final*** whenever I have a `|` in the request. In these cases it looks like the request is not even hitting my breakpoints.

I can programmatically do a dirty fix by URL encoding all `|` in our `$.ajaxSetup`, but this only fixes requests originating from the server itself, and not requests that are coming externally with `|` in their `GET` request query params.

The dirty (and insufficient) fix:

```js
  $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
      settings.url = settings.url.replace(/\|\|/g, "%7C%7C");
    }
  });
```

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Full `standalone.xml` (with sensitivre info masked) [here](https://gist.github.com/martoncsukas/5cd01c439b54eb448c8bf29ed55b0a82).

EDIT: In the meantime I noticed that this issue only happens when I hit endpoints defined in Windows `hosts` file. When I go through our company's load balancer, it works fine.

So e.g. http://localhost.myproduct.com is not working from SERVER1 if `127.0.0.1  localhost.myproduct.com` is in `hosts` file, but https://server1.myproduct.com that hits the very same server works fine, if the endpoint is routed through the load balancer.

Answer (score 3):

I saw a few related postings around this time, all of which seem to have gone unanswered.

I've also encountered a similar issue with Wildfly 23.0.0.Final, which was a problem with http/2 handling - there is a fix for that: [UndertowOptions.ALLOW_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS_IN_URL has no effect for HTTP/2](https://issues.redhat.com/projects/UNDERTOW/issues/UNDERTOW-1882), but as of this reply AFAIK is not yet released in a Wildfly build.

Setting `enable-http2="false"` on the listeners - while not ideal - worked around the problem for me.

It could be that your load balancer is doing http/1.1 on the backend which would be why you don't encounter the problem when routing through it.

Comment: What is the correct solution for this?

Comment: The correct solution would be not to use unsafe characters in the URL. If you don't have control over that...

The bug referenced in my answer appears to be fixed as of WildFly 25.0.0.Final, which will allow them with HTTP/2.

enable-http2="false" will work around the HTTP/2 issue with older releases.

allow-unescaped-characters-in-url="true" still needs to be specified (also) on the listeners in any case for undertow to accept these characters in the URL.